# NaN and zero values when using svyciprop on subgroups via subset or svyby

Tags: r, survey, weighted

I'm new to post-stratification and the `survey` package in R, so apologies if I've missed something obvious here! Very grateful for any suggestions of what's going on or what to try...

Unfortunately, this doesn't contain a minimal reproducible example, as I've not yet managed to recreate the problem outside my data (which I can't share).

### Problem

I am running `svyciprop` on post-stratified data (from `survey` package, v4.1-1, in R). I am using it either with `svyby` or `subset` to get proportions of an outcome in subgroups e.g. something like (where `dat` is the sample and `dat_pop` is the population):

```
svydat <- svydesign(~1, data = dat, weights = ~1)
svydat <- postStratify(svydat, strata = ~sex, population = table(sex = dat_pop$sex))
svyciprop(~outcome, design = subset(svydat, group == "a"))
```

Sometimes, I get either all `NaN` values for the estimate and its confidence intervals, or all `0` values. (The all-0-values are clearly wrong based on the data). There's not an obvious pattern to when this happens.

It also gives this warning (repeated twice) - although I also get this in cases where it appears to return a reasonable output:

```
1: In summary.glm(g) :
  observations with zero weight not used for calculating dispersion
```

### Additional details

There are a number of closely-related circumstances in which I don't see the same thing:

- Restricting my data to the subgroup I want to look at before doing post-stratification.
- Running `svyciprop` on the full data.
- Using `method = "beta"`, `method = "asin"`, `method = "mean"` or `method = "xlogit"` for the confidence intervals (these return sensible-looking results).
- On the other hand, `method = "likelihood"` does not produce any result and fails with this error message:

```
Error in seq.int(xmin, xmax, length.out = n) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
```

and an additional warning:

```
3: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
```

- Running `svyciprop` on the same data, but weighted by explicitly specifying the weight argument rather than by post-stratification. (This includes when using inverse probabilities from a logistic regression model with all cross-terms, to approximate the post-stratification scenario).

### Edit: reproducible example (2023-04-11)

Here's some artificial data that recreates the issue:

```
library(survey)
# Make data -------------------------------------- 

# I'm making three separate datasets then combining them
# For the simulated group on which data is available, making "a" and "b" groups separately 
# Then making the group of people who do not have data, who can belong to both "a" and "b" group
dat_a <-
  data.frame(
    group = "a",
    sex = c(rep("M", 3000), rep("F", 4000), rep("M", 9000), rep("F", 8000)),
    outcome = c(rep(F, 3000 + 4000), rep(T, 9000 + 8000)),
    inc = 1
  )
dat_b <-
  data.frame(
    group = "b",
    sex = c(rep("M", 30), rep("F", 50), rep("M", 120), rep("F", 160)),
    outcome = c(rep(F, 30 + 50), rep(T, 120 + 160)),
    inc = 1
  )
dat_out <-
  data.frame(
    group = c(rep("a", 20 + 30), rep("b", 2000 + 2500)),
    sex = c(rep("M", 20), rep("F", 30), rep("M", 2000), rep("F", 2500)),
    outcome = NA,
    inc = 0
    )


dat_all <- rbind(dat_a, dat_b, dat_out)
dat_inc <- dat_all[dat_all$inc == 1, ]           

# Perform post stratification ------------------------
svydat <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = dat_inc, weights = ~1)
svydat_ps <- postStratify(svydat, strata = ~sex, population = table(sex = dat_all$sex))


# Demonstrate failure of certain type of CI (but not others) when using svyciprop -----------------------------
for (method in  c( "asin", "beta",
                  "mean","xlogit", "logit",  "likelihood")){
  print(method)
  print(svyby(~ outcome, ~ group, svydat_ps, svyciprop, vartype = "ci", method = method))
}


# This problem in a couple of methods for CIs can be traced to svyglm ------------------------------------------
mygroup <- "b"
design <- subset(svydat_ps, group == mygroup)
svyglm(outcome ~ 1, design, 
       family = quasibinomial)$coef

# Interestingly, it doesn't seem to have a problem if I force the start (suggesting it's a convergence issue?):
svyglm(outcome ~ 1, design, 
       family = quasibinomial, start = 0)$coef
```

Comment: It sounds as if you've made some attempts, but I strongly recommend that you continue trying to generate some data you can share that causes the same error. Without doing this, the only way anyone can answer this question is if they happen to have encountered the exact same problem. Bonus point: if you do manage to recreate the error, you may work out what is causing the issue. If so please post an answer!

Comment: hi, maybe `debug(survey:::svyciprop)` will help you narrow down the issue?

Comment: Thanks. On minimal example, I'll keep trying.

Using debug, the issue is introduced at the call to `svyglm` in `svyciprop`. I can then recreate it outside: 

Most of the time, calling `svyglm(outcome ~ 1, design = subset(svydat, group == "a"), family = quasibinomial))`  gives same intercept as making the survey design object on the subset and then calling `svyglm` (provided group included in strata). However, in the cases where I'm having issues it appears not to converge at all (coefficient essentially 0 or infinite). So something about `subset` seems to mean it's getting stuck?

Comment: The warning is harmless. The proximate cause is that for post-stratified design objects, subset works by setting weights outside the subset to zero.   It would be good to get an example for the answers that you think are wrong, though

Comment: Thanks. Will have another go at generating dummy data.

Comment: I've now managed to make some dummy data which exhibits this behaviour, and have added it to the post above. Thanks again for any advice!